# Header Operation is Required SOAP Call in SOAP UI

Tags: soap, soapui, httpresponse

Just trying to understand the issues presented here.

I am using SOPA UI 5.7.0 to test some web services.

The issue presented is "Header Operation is required".

I am performing a test upon an existing operation so I am unsure of the missing requirement any help appreciated.

[image]

Regards

Comment: In the request editor, right click and validate the request and see.